# Cmocka tests do not show any output

Tags: c, unit-testing, cmocka

I have downloaded the [cmocka example files](https://git.cryptomilk.org/projects/cmocka.git/snapshot/cmocka-1.0.1.zip) and followed all the instructions. All test files were succesfully generated and I can run them, but no output appears in the console. I have tried to alter the `CMOCKA_MESSAGE_OUTPUT` environmental variable, tried to write my own tests and compile them, tried to recompile and reinstall cmocka several times - nothing made the tests output anything. I work on Windows 7 32-bit, so I figured to try also cygwin, but cygwin just throws that it cannot find public libraries, so I abandoned this fork of my research - after all cmocka should also normally work in windows cmd. Does anyone know how to make the tests output anything to the console?

**EDIT**

I'm adding my make info in case there was some problem with compilation/linking, although I don't see any (it doesn't produce any error and outputs correctly the tests.exe file):

```
# Makefile
OBJ_DIR = obj
HDR = $(wildcard *.h)
SRC = $(HDR:.h=.c)
OBJ = $(HDR:%.h=$(OBJ_DIR)\\%.o)
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -I"C:\Program Files\cmocka\include" -I"C:\Program Files\cmocka\lib" -I"C:\Program Files\cmocka\bin" -llibcmocka -lcmocka

.PHONY: all clean

all: tests.exe

$(OBJ_DIR)\\%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) $< -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)\tests.o: tests.c
    $(CC) $< -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

tests.exe: $(OBJ) $(OBJ_DIR)\tests.o
    $(CC) $^ -o tests.exe $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    del $(OBJ) $(OBJ_DIR)\tests.o tests.exe
```

note1: the numerous paths in cflags are put out of desperation - at first I had been using only the first one.

note2: when I try to run this script in Netbeans or cygwin I change `del` to `rm -f` and switch slashes. The output is like described above: the make is done without any errors and outputs the `tests.exe`, but once executed, it throws error about not being able to find public libraries.

Comment: I have just noticed something that may be useful: when I put `cmocka_set_message_output(CM_OUTPUT_STDOUT);` in the `main()` function, the linker says that the reference is undefined. This is strange to me since `cmocka_run_group_tests()` and `cmocka_unit_test()` works fine.

To explain: I copied the libraries files to my project folder and run all gcc commands to compile my tests with `-Icmocka -lcmocka` flags, where _cmocka_ is the folder with library files (libcmocka.a, libcmocka.dll).

Answer (score 1):

The symbol is not exported, see https://git.cryptomilk.org/projects/cmocka.git/commit/?id=7364469189558a8720b60880940a41e1a0d20452

Comment: Ok, thanks for quick reaction. But this still doesn't solve the main problem that the **tests don't output anything on the console**. Since you're the creator of cmocka, do you know what may be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for digging out this old thread, but i recently stumbled over exactly the same problem. Compiled everything by myself with meson/ninja and did not get any output neither from the test itself, nor from a simple printf.

I solved the problem by using the precompiled library from [here](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-cmocka).
Just install/start MSYS2 and use
for 64-bit MINGW:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmocka
```

for 32-bit MINGW:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-cmocka
```

Then I recompiled my hello world test, and output worked as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and for me it was that I had not properly passed the `state` argument to the tests. My tests had this signature:

```
void test_something() { /* ...snip... */ }
```

but it should have been

```
void test_something(void **state) {
    (void) state;  /* unused */
    /* ...snip... */
}
```

After fixing this, the output properly appeared.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in the tests.c that has the unit tests, not your setup. Show us your tests.c file where you wrote your unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem.
Especially I also used gcov to see the coverage and it claims that nothing gets ever executed.

My solution was that I just forgot to add cmocka to my environment-path. After adding "cmocka.dll" to the path everything finally works.